# Manager isn't accessible via __ instances when getting model objects

Tags: python, django

I'm just transitioning to python. I just cant populate my html list from data in models.

here's my model just to show details but i think there's nothing wrong here

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    student_id =  models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key = True)
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    course = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    section = models.CharField(max_length=1)
```

Here is the view and the html file that I'm not sure where I messed up

view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .models import Student

@login_required
def home(request):
    student = Student
    return render(request, 'studentapp/studenthome.html', {
        'student':student,
    })
```

studenthome.hmtl

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Student Home</h2>

<ul>
    {% for students in student.objects.all %}
    <li>{{students.first_name }} {{students.middle_name}} {{ students.last_name }}</li>
    {%  endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

I think the error is related to the for statement here in html file but I really have no idea

Error: Manager isn't accessible via Student instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query from model to fetch data.

You ned to chnages in `views.py`
Change `student = Student` to `student = Student.objects.all()`

And in template
you this instead of your existing one:

```
{% for students in student %}
    <li>{{students.first_name }} {{students.middle_name}} {{ students.last_name }}</li>
{%  endfor %}
```

Comment: The code is working great. However, I wonder If there is really something wrong or the IDE is not just intelligent enough because it shows "Student has no 'object' member"